# Get random number in sequence C++

Tags: c++, random, generator

Is there a way using the C++ standard library built in random generator to get a specific random number in a sequence, without saving them all?

Like

```
srand(cTime);
getRand(1); // 10
getRand(2); // 8995
getRand(3); // 65464456
getRand(1); // 10
getRand(2); // 8995
getRand(1); // 10
getRand(3); // 65464456
```

Comment: Using a tweak you can generate random numbers within a specific range, like if you need random numbers only from 0-36 then you can easily achive that, using % operator(like rand()%36) with the rand() function, but I am not aware of any built in function , which will take X as input for getRand(X) and generate something f(X) everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 random number engines are required to implement a member function `discard(unsigned long long z)` (§26.5.1.4) that advances the random number sequence by `z` steps. The complexity guarantee is quite weak: "no worse than
the complexity of `z` consecutive calls `e()`". This member obviously exists solely to make it possible to expose more performant implementations when possible as note 274 states:

> This operation is common in user code, and can often be implemented
>   in an engine-specific manner so as to provide significant performance
>   improvements over an equivalent naive loop that makes `z` consecutive
>   calls `e()`.

Given `discard` you can easily implement your requirement to retrieve the `n`th number in sequence by reseeding a generator, discarding `n-1` values and using the next generated value.

I'm unaware of which - if any - of the standard RNG engines are amenable to efficient implementations of `discard`. It may be worth your time to do a bit of investigation and profiling.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the numbers. There may be other variants, but it still requires saving a list of numbers (e.g. using different seeds based on the argument to `getRand()` - but that wouldn't really be beneficial over saving them).

Something like this would work reasonably well, I'd say:

```
int getRand(int n)
{
    static std::map<int, int> mrand;
    // Check if it's there. 
    if ((std::map::iterator it = mrand.find(n)) != mrand.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    int r = rand();
    mrand[n] = r;
    return r;
}
```

(I haven't compiled this code, just written it up as a "this sort of thing might work")

Comment: Saving isn't an option, there can be millions of numbers depending on how long the application is running.

Comment: Well, you can't get the same number twice without saving either the number, or using a new (but the same) seed each time. Note that saving millions of numbers shouldn't be a problem in a modern computer - even a mobile phone has many megabytes of memory these days. 1M numbers = ~ 4MB (although a `map` will possibly take up a bit more space). The whole point of `rand` is that it generates a different number each time you call it. You can of course call `srand` with a new seed each time, but that would require saving and generating good seeds for each sequence number, so that's even worse.

Comment: How do you achieve this in Java then?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `getRand()` to always seed and then return the given number. This will interfere with all other random numbers in a system, though, and will be slow, especially for large indexes. Assuming a 1-based index:

```
int getRand(int index)
{
    srand(999);  // fix the seed
    for (int loop=1; loop<index; ++loop)
        rand();
    return rand();
}
```

Comment: I just read another comment "there can be millions of numbers depending on how long the application is running" - while this will do what you asked, it won't be practical for such large indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to cdmh's post,

Following from C++11 could also be used :

```
#include<random>

long getrand(int index)
{
 std::default_random_engine e;
 for(auto i=1;i<index;i++)
     e();
  return e();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out: 
[Random123](http://www.deshawresearch.com/resources_random123.html)

From the documentation:

> Random123 is a library of "counter-based" random number generators (CBRNGs), in which the Nth random number can be obtained by applying a stateless mixing function to N..